# Naming a FK for a Post Author

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables

```
create table dbo.Users (
  UserId int identity not null,
  Name nvarchar (400) not null
)

create table dbo.Posts (
  PostId int identity not null,
  UserId int not null,
  Title nvarchar (400) not null,
  Content nvarchar (max) not null,
)
```

On table Posts UserId is the author of the post and it is a FK to Users.UserId PK.

In this situations should I name the column UserId which is clear what the relation is or AuthorId describing of it is withing the post?

What is the most common approach for this naming?

Comment: This calls for opinions instead of facts. 
I would keep it UserId, as it is more clear and intuitive regarding your database structure. When selecting the Name from User then I would give it an alias "Author" and that's about it.

Comment: This is based upon opinion off course. I always use the name of this table and the name of the referring table, in this example the name of the field is UserID and the foreign key would be FK_POSTS_USERS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a rule, I try to name foreign key relationships with the same name as the primary key.  So I would use:

```
create table dbo.Posts (
    PostId int identity not null,
    UserId int not null,  -- this is the author of the post
    Title nvarchar(400) not null,
    Content nvarchar(max) not null,
    constraint fk_posts_userid foreign key (UserId) references Users(UserId)
);
```

I find that this makes it *much* easier to write queries and to follow queries that have been written.  This is also practical in databases that support ANSI standard `USING` syntax.

The one exception is when there are multiple references to the same reference table.  Then I try to include the primary key name in the column name:

```
create table dbo.Posts (
    PostId int identity not null,
    Author_UserId int not null,  -- this is the author of the post
    Approver_UserId int not null,
    Title nvarchar(400) not null,
    Content nvarchar(max) not null,
    constraint fk_posts_authoruserid foreign key (Author_UserId) references Users(UserId),
    constraint fk_posts_approveruserid foreign key (Approver_UserId) references Users(UserId)
);
```

Admittedly, this is not the only style for naming, so the answer is a a matter of (informed) opinion.  Many databases name the `id` column `id`, for instance, so you couldn't follow this convention.

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree with Gordon's convention except that I don't use underscores in column names.

Answer (score 3):

I always use the names of the tables in the foreign key name, the foreign key field I usually name the same as in the refering table.

In this example that would be

```
create table dbo.Users (
  UserId int identity not null,
  Name nvarchar (400) not null,

  constraint PK_UserId primary key (UserId)
)

create table dbo.Posts (
  PostId int identity not null,
  UserId int not null,
  Title nvarchar (400) not null,
  Content nvarchar (max) not null,

  constraint PK_PostId primary key (PostId),
  constraint FK_Posts_Users foreign key (UserId) references Users (UserId)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one reasonable naming standard, but a scheme I like for keys is:

*Primary Key* is the entity name followed by `_ID` (or `Id` if you're using camel-case as you show, but I typically don't in SQL).

*Foregin Key* is the referenced entity name followed by `_ID` (or `Id` blah blah); optionally preceded by a role identifier if needed for clarity.

So `UserId` (though I'd spell it `USER_ID`) is fine; or `AuthorUserId`.  I don't like `AuthorId` because there's no `AUTHOR` table.

It's just a layer of clarity.  Ideally you'd have descriptions in a data dictionary, and of course someone could look at the actual FK constraints (assuming you use actual FK constraints) but having conventions that let someone know at a glance what's happening is better.

...A minor update...

Regarding the very similar answer from Gordon Linoff, I think the only thing I'd put differently is the point about a role-naming prefix.  Certainly having multiple FK's that point to the same table is the most common case where role-naming is absolutely necessary, but I advocate using them any time the relationship meaning would otherwise be unclear.  Your `ORDER` table only has the billing address and not the shipping address or whatever?  Fine, but I'd still call it 'BILLING_ADDRESS_ID'

And there is one other case where a role name is basically required: self-reference.  `EMPLOYEE_ID` can have a `MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID`...